# Add extra columns to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm preparing my lab-report. I need to customize my ToC for this. To be specific, I need to add two extra columns to the table of contents page, viz., Date and Evaluator's signature. These columns can be entry, but i need to add them to the ToC. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick hack:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,titletoc}

\titlecontents{section}
[0em]
{}
{}
{}
{\titlerule*[0.5em]{.}\contentspage}

%\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Date & Signature \\[1em]
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\[12pt]
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1in}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\vspace{1in}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Date & Signature \\[1em]
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\[12pt]
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}


\section{Joe}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Blow}

\lipsum[3]

\section{A longer section title intended to take more than one line}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Blow}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Joe}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Blow}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Joe}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Blow}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

It seems that loading package `titletoc` allows you to put the TOC into a minipage. You would still have to manually align the content of the second minipage with the entries in the TOC. In the updated example, I have used two minipages to illustrate how to vertically shift their content.

As I said, it's just a hack; there should be a better way.

[image]

Comment: that almost did it. But, how do i lift date and sign to the bottom of my page to align with my contents? Now, date and sign lie almost at the middle of the page, to the right

Comment: Insert vertical space manually using `\vspace`, see updated example.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer What if the ToC spans more than a page, then minipage just hides the remaining entries. Any solution for that case?

Answer (score 6):

It's possible with `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\quad\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}\quad\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{This is one}

\section{This is two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is clearly better than my answer. Good to know.