# Adding date column to Table of Contents in KOMA-script scrbook class

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook

Since accepting [Jasper Habicht's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht) working answer to [my earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621301/adding-date-column-to-table-of-contents), I have switched from standard `book`-class to KOMA-script's `scrbook`. I still need to add a specific column to my ToC, and the following MWE is a `book`-class solution that unfortunately no longer works for me in the KOMA-script environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\toclineinsert}[3][25mm]{%
    \dotfill\ #2\makebox[#1][l]{#3\dotfill}%
}

\title{test}
\author{name}
\date{now}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{first lecture title \toclineinsert{4 }{January}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{second lecture title \toclineinsert{2nd half }{January}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{third lecture title \toclineinsert{February/}{March}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{a pretty long fourth lecture title \newline that goes over two lines \toclineinsert{29 or 30 }{March}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table of Contents]

How can achieve the same (or similar) in the `scrbook` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill={},% default for chapter is linefill=\hfill
]{tocline}{chapter}
```

to the preamble.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill={},
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand{\toclineinsert}[3][25mm]{%
    \dotfill
    \ #2\makebox[#1][l]{#3\dotfill}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{first lecture title \toclineinsert{4 }{January}}
\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{second lecture title \toclineinsert{2nd half }{January}}
\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{third lecture title \toclineinsert{February/}{March}}
\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{a pretty long fourth lecture title \newline that goes over two lines \toclineinsert{29 or 30 }{March}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe you want to use `\addchap` with its optional argument. Then you can set class option `headings=optiontotocandhead` to activate the advanced functionality of the optional argument of the sectioning commands.

```latex
\documentclass[headings=optiontotocandhead]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill={},
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand{\toclineinsert}[3][25mm]{%
    \dotfill
    \ #2\makebox[#1][l]{#3\dotfill}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap
  [tocentry={first lecture title \toclineinsert{4 }{January}}]
  {first lecture title}
\lipsum[1-20]

\addchap
  [tocentry={second lecture title \toclineinsert{2nd half }{January}},head={different entry in page header}]
  {second lecture title}
\lipsum[1-20]

\addchap
  [tocentry={third lecture title \toclineinsert{February/}{March}}]
  {third lecture title}
\addchap
  [tocentry={a pretty long fourth lecture title \newline that goes over two lines \toclineinsert{29 or 30 }{March}}]
  {a pretty long fourth lecture title that goes over two lines}
\end{document}
```