# Issue with hyperref in scrbook

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, scrbook

I need my ToC entries, the entries in my index and my glossary to navigate the reader of the PDF to the appropriate place. However, loading the `hyperref` package produces a fatal error. My guess is it has something to do with the way I customised the appearance of the ToC, but I'm not yet experienced enough to figure out where and how I am confusing the program. How to fix this?

My MWE is this `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[dutch,british,UKenglish]{babel}
\KOMAoptions{headings=small}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fnpct}
%commands re the ToC
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill={},
]{tocline}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand \Dotfill {\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ 0.75em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\toclineinsert}[3][14mm]{%
    \Dotfill #2\makebox[#1][l]{#3\Dotfill}%
}

\title{MWE}
\author{name}
\date{now}


%everything re the glossary
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

    \newglossaryentry{ips}
    {
        name=\emph{lorem},
        description={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis}
    }
    

%commands relating to footnote formatting:
\KOMAoptions{footnotes=multiple}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\color{lightgray}\thefootnotemark\ \ }
\setkomafont{footnote}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{\raggedleft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}%Indexing package
\makeindex[intoc,options= -s index_style.ist,name=m,title=\mbox{Index},columns=2]
\makeindex[options= -s index_style.ist, intoc,name=p,title=\mbox{List of names},columns=2]

%enabling the entry of numberless footnotes that don't mess up the numbering
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans} 
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\AlegreyaOsF #1}}

%hyphenation
\pretolerance=9000
\tolerance=2000 
\emergencystretch=8pt


%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\addchap[tocentry={\emph{Preface}}, head={\textsc{preface}}]
  {Preface}

\lipsum[1-6]

\mainmatter

\setchapterpreamble[o]{%
\dictum[]{Location\\ Date}}
\addchap[tocentry={Lecture title \toclineinsert{\normalfont{ lecture date}}},head={}]{Lecture title}\index[m]{aaa|(}

\blfootnote{\newline \lipsum[1]
\newline}
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}\index[m]{bbb!aaa}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.\index[m]{ccc!aaa|(}

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. \index[m]{ddd}\index[m]{ddd!aaa} Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.\footnote{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.} Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.\index[m]{eee}\index[m]{fff!aaa} Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.\footnote{Mauris ut leo} Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.\index[m]{ggg|(}. 

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris\index[m]{hhh}\index[m]{hhh!aaa}. \lipsum[1] \index[m]{ggg|)}\index[m]{iii!aaa} \lipsum[1] \index[m]{jjj!kkk} \lipsum[1] \index[m]{kkk!jjj}. \lipsum[1] Mauris ut leo.\footnote{Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris}\footnote{Curabitur auctor semper nulla}\lipsum[1]\index[m]{ccc!aaa|)}

\index[m]{lll!aaa|(} Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.\footnote{Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia} \lipsum[1]\index[m]{lll!aaa|)} \footnote{ Donec bibendum quam in tellus.
Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus}

\lipsum[1-2]\index[m]{mmm!aaa} \lipsum[1] \index[m]{nnn!aaa} Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo\index[m]{ppp!aaa}, dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.

\lipsum[1] \index[m]{ppp!bbb}.

 \Gls{ips} ipsum. \lipsum[1]

\addsec*{Nam dui ligula}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\index[m]{ppp!ccc} consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque\index[m]{qqq!aaa}. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.\index[m]{rrr!aaa} \lipsum[1] \index[m]{sss!aaa} Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae
risus porta vehicula. \index[m]{aaa|)}

\printindex[m]

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Together with this `index_sty.ist` file:

```
heading_prefix "\n\\raggedright\\large\\sffamily\\normalfont%
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"

item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 " \\Dotfill "
delim_1 " \\Dotfill "
delim_2 " \\Dotfill "
```

Comment: your document errors for me even without hyperref.

Comment: Really? Hhmmm... What errors did you get? Did you add the `index_sty.ist` file to the root?

Comment: you can try it here: https://texlive.net/run. The pdflatex run errors with `! Argument of \\toclineinsert has an extra }.`  The `ist`  is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks: I've edited the MWE so that it now works.

Comment: it still breaks, and I can't see how it can work for you, your `\toclineinsert`  takes two mandatory argument, but you are giving it only one.

Comment: I also think that your example is missing some options for scrbook.

Comment: So re the `\toclineinsert`, here I tinkered with the results of [Jasper Habricht's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht) answer to my [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621301/adding-date-column-to-table-of-contents). I think the issue is with me not fully understanding the macro he wrote. 

Strange that the MWE is still not working for you - I'm getting a PDF from texlive.net, but no index or glossary in it, where on overleaf these are included. 

Which options for `scrbook` are you missing?